# Google Kubernetes Engine - From External IP to Cloud Endpoint Configuration

Tags: kubernetes, ip, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a cluster with multiple nodes. I've set up a Cloud Endpoints Portal and deployed my `api_config.yaml`

```
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#
# A Bookstore example API configuration.
#
# Below, replace MY_PROJECT_ID with your Google Cloud Project ID.
#

# The configuration schema is defined by service.proto file
# https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/service.proto
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3

#
# Name of the service configuration.
#
name: MY-SERVICE.service.endpoints.MY-PROJECT-ID.cloud.goog

#
# API title to appear in the user interface (Google Cloud Console).
#
title: MyService gRPC API
apis:
  - name: endpoints.MY-PROJECT-ID.service.MY-SERVICE.MyService
```

My issue is I think pretty simple: **How can I use the url as API endpoint instead of the external IP of my node?** Because if my IP change, I don't want to have to change anything in the code in term on configuration, but just update my 'addresses binding'

I can access the API Documentation from the URL and my service is available from the External IP. I am just looking to bind these both

Right now I have the following behavior:

```
MBP-de-Emixam23:service-interface emixam23$ gcloud endpoints services deploy service.pb api_config.yaml
ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert to service config.
'location: "api_config.yaml:36"
kind: ERROR
message: "Cannot resolve api \'endpoints.MY-PROJECT-ID.service.MY-SERVICE.MyService\'."
'
```

Thanks!

## EDIT v2 (based on Andres S comment/answer)

```
host: "<YOUR_NAMING>.endpoints.YOUR_PROJECT_ID.cloud.goog"
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "<YOUR_NAMING>.endpoints.YOUR_PROJECT_ID.cloud.goog"
  target: "IP_ADDRESS"
# host: "test.service.endpoints.example-project.cloud.goog"
  # x-google-endpoints:
  # - name: "test.service.endpoints.example-project.cloud.goog"
  # target: "23.11.95.72"
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) Unable to parse Open API, or Google Service Configuration specification from api_config.yaml

Comment: I followed the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine#configuring-endpoints-dns) and was able to reach the endpoint by its URL, you can check it out [here](http://echo-api.endpoints.omega-keep-248914.cloud.goog/) I am thinking that maybe something is wrong with the api_config.yaml, could you share it? Are you replacing the projectid in the url ?

Comment: You have it already in the question, thanks for your help

Comment: I know, check my update, My api_config.yaml look like the second piece of code now

Comment: I am not sure if this is due the UI in stackoverflow, but in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine#configuring-endpoints-dns) the 3 first lines have no indentation, only the fourth line _target..._ has one blank space before, and the first step specifies _not indented or nested_ but in the one you shared each line has an incremental indentation, this may be worth changing and trying

Comment: Even like that, I get `UNABLE TO PARSE OPEN API`..

Comment: I tested the v2 code you added, and I was able to make it work [here](http://yournaming.endpoints.omega-keep-248914.cloud.goog/) (It will throw an error because that API from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine) is expecting to be used with curl and some params) so the issue is not there, I compared the rest of the yaml with the [github one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/getting-started/openapi.yaml) and its a little different (like the swagger part missing), not sure what is the parse issue

Comment: I don’t need the swagger part, here I just want to be able to access the IP from a given domain name

Comment: Apologies, I think it was the wrong quickstart that was suggested as you are using a gRPC api, the DNS settings suggested are not correct for this case, I will update my answer with the right ones from [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/cloud-goog-dns-configure)

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry didn't I mention gRPC?

Comment: It was in the service title and I should have noticed, anyway I hope the new information helps :)

Answer (score 1):

These lines have to be added to your api_config.yaml according to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/cloud-goog-dns-configure)

```
endpoints:
- name: name.projectid.cloud.goog
  target: "X.X.X.X"
```

I tested by following the [quickstart for gRPC endpoints / GKE](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-kubernetes-engine)

And ultimately was able to get an answer from the endpoint using the domain

(emerald-cumulus-260322 is my temporal projectid used for testing)

```
$ python bookstore_client.py --host bookstore.endpoints.emerald-cumulus-260322.cloud.goog --port 80                                 
ListShelves: shelves {
  id: 1
  theme: "Fiction"
}
shelves {
  id: 2
  theme: "Fantasy"
}
```

My final api_config.yaml looks like this:

```
# Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#
# A Bookstore example API configuration.
#
# Below, replace MY_PROJECT_ID with your Google Cloud Project ID.
#

# The configuration schema is defined by service.proto file
# https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/service.proto
type: google.api.Service
name: bookstore.endpoints.projectidhere.cloud.goog
endpoints:
- name: bookstore.endpoints.projectidhere.cloud.goog
  target: "X.X.X.X"

config_version: 3

#
# Name of the service configuration.
#

#
# API title to appear in the user interface (Google Cloud Console).
#
title: Bookstore gRPC API
apis:
- name: endpoints.examples.bookstore.Bookstore

#
# API usage restrictions.
#
usage:
  rules:
  # ListShelves methods can be called without an API Key.
  - selector: endpoints.examples.bookstore.Bookstore.ListShelves
    allow_unregistered_calls: true
```

Comment: I did tried your link (the first one I followed actually), and I get an error. Please see Edit V2

Comment: I will take a look at it once I have time, let me come back to you :) thanks for your help, appreciate that!

Comment: No problem! ok!

Comment: I had a lot of work so I am getting back into it now, I will comment if I have any issue :)

Comment: I did work on it, thanks for your help! I don't want to put any API restriction for now, how can I do it?

Comment: Ok so I will update my question, I don't get why it is SO COMPLICATED to bind a simple IP:PORT with a domain ...

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible.

Here's the [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine#configuring-endpoints-dns) to openapi but that might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am currently following that link but the yaml throws errors..

Comment: Could you please post the specific error you are getting when trying to use said FQDN?

Also, have you tried to configure a DNS for your endpoint (perhaps this might make it possible).